# Two jQuery apps on page only one working at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a site I am working on. http://peterseabrook.com/galaxias2/.

I have two javascript scripts executing some jQuery but only 1 will work at a time depending on which code comes first for the clocks or for the jPlayer radio.

I have no idea what to do here.

CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#clock_sydney').jClocksGMT({offset: '+11'});
            $('#clock_greece').jClocksGMT({offset: '+3'});
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var stream = {
    title: "Galaxias Radio",
    mp3: "http://78.46.52.186:18272/;/stream/1"
},
ready = false;

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        ready = true;
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
    },
    pause: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
    },
    error: function(event) {
        if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
            // Setup the media stream again and play it.
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
        }
    },
    swfPath: "http://peterseabrook.com/galaxias2/wp-content/themes/canvas/js/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    preload: "none",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    keyEnabled: true
});


$("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
```

});
Thanks in advance guys,

Peter.

Comment: I don't know if it affects you, but JavaScript is single threaded: only one code is running at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

did you call both functions? if not you can call both into one function.

> function twoFunctions(){
>             firstFunction();
>             secondFunction();
>   }

Comment: Could you possibly show me with the code I provided above in the edit?